Record if assert are used in a model
I am currently developing a model (within Dymola env) that use a lot of components.
Each of these components use some kinds of functions to determinate their behaviour.
All of these functions have their own bound of validity but can be used (via extrapolation) outside of their bound.
So I am using assert function like
 assert(noEvent(P>1e5), "Pressure used to compute is out the minimal bound", AssertionLevel.warning);

In order to know if I am out of the validity range.
This model shall be exported to an FMU to be used by an other tool.
In a first part I am not interested to read all the log file generated during the simulation to know which assert came true.
My question is :
Is there a way to obtain some kind of information (i.e a boolean) that indicates that at least one assert came true? (or a real with the number of assert)
The idea is to read this information by an output of the FMU. If the information came true, then I would have to read the log to find what gone wrong.
There is obviously the solution to "duplicate" each assert, to create a Boolean and report its value for each component. But this solution seems a little "heavy" and requires modifying each component.
Thank you for your idea!
